# Calling a Generic Method with Lambda Expressions parameter (and a Type only known at runtime)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda, reflection

I have a Repository:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : ICommandRepository<TEntity>, IBaseRepository, IDisposable, IQueryableRepository<TEntity>
{
}
public interface ICommandRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository, IDisposable
{
    void Delete(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);     
}
```

My Goal is to invoke Delete method with Lamda Expresion Params, if I know the Type of "TEntity" in runtime. 
Example, how I call this method:

```
public JsonResult DeleteRows(int[] ids)
{
    var repo = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRepository<WORKINGHOURS>>();
    repo.Delete(e => ids.Contains(e.Id));
    repo.UnitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Now, I want to invoke same method using reflection and Type on runtime:

```
public JsonResult DeleteRows(string type, int[] ids)
{
    Type dbObjectType = Type.GetType(type);
    Type repositoryType = typeof (IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(dbObjectType);
    var repositoryInstance = ServiceLocator.CurrentLifetimeScope.Resolve(repositoryType);

    MethodInfo deleteMethod = repositoryType.GetMethod("Delete");
    // TODO:
    // Expression<Func<WORKINGHOURS, bool>> searchQuery = p => ids.Contains(p.Id);
    var delete = deleteMethod.Invoke(repositoryInstance, .....);
    // Commit
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, please explain exactly what the question is. Is it to construct the expression?

Comment: Could you perhaps write your own generic method that contains normal C# code inside that constructs that expression, and call *that* method using reflection?

Comment: Thanks Lasse for your response, I will defiantly do this if no other solution can be found.